# filtering column values while using SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, filter

I have a mysql table with a column Doc TEXT.

the column contains HTML as content.

I want to select the column with filtered to get only URLs from the content. column content contains A HREF="(.*)" .

I tried mysql's REGEXP, but it will return only true or false, not the filtered match.

highly appreciate your help.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any built-in functions for doing pattern extraction from strings. Google for regular expression UDFs.

Comment: Whilst one could fairly easily extract patterns that match a URL string (wherever they appear within the document) using @Barmar's suggestion, one cannot use that approach to restrict one's search to the `href` attribute of anchor elements (as HTML is not a regular language).  However, if the document happens to be well-formed **XHTML**, one could use MySQL's [`ExtractValue()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML column text is well-defined XML (i.e. XHTML with proper closing tags) you can use MySQL's `extractValue()` function to parse it as XML using Xpath.

```
CREATE TABLE links (anchor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO links VALUES ('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>');

SELECT extractValue(anchor, '/a/@href') FROM links; -- prints http://stackoverflow.com/
```

If the column contains other tags (like `<body>` etc.) just modify your Xpath (`//body/a/@href`) accordingly.

**EDIT**: For the column HTML shared in your comments below:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>*******</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><P><A HREF="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</A></P><div><A HREF="http://www.yahoo.com">YAHOO</A></DIV><TABLE><TR><TD><A HREF="http://www.bing.com">BING</A></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

The `extractValue()` xpath needs to be modifed to `//A/@HREF` (case-sensitive)

```
SELECT extractValue(anchor, '//A/@HREF') FROM links;
-- prints http://www.google.com http://www.yahoo.com http://www.bing.com
```

Also, notice that closing `<div>` with `</DIV>` is not proper XML but somehow MySQL ignored it.

Comment: Er.. well defined HTML *cannot* be treated as XML.  Consider `<br>` (no close tag).

Comment: Well-defined HTML = XHTML = XML. Or, maybe I could have just said `if your HTML is well-defined XML` to cut any confusion over this. Yes, it does sound ambiguous to me now. :)

Comment: "Well defined" (I presume you mean "well formed") HTML is not XHTML.  They are two different (albeit closely related) languages, with two different definitions.  But I agree with your edits (albeit they merely repeat [my earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622066/filtering-column-values-while-using-select-in-mysql/16622254?noredirect=1#comment23900094_16622066)).

Comment: Hmm.. well apparently I haven't gone through the W3C specification as many times as you have. But, I still don't have any troubles getting my point across. I actually didn't want to even mention XHTML in my answer because I usually stay on the topic and don't like to deviate at all *unless* it helps. And my edit it merely states a fact that must have been stated by countless other people before you as well. If you still think you stated something so enlightening that none of the fellow web developers already knew you have my permission to go ahead, edit my post and put yourself in reference.

Comment: Wow, gosh.  I'm sorry that I somehow offended you so deeply to have warranted that rebuke.  I was merely trying to help the OP understand that your method wouldn't work unless the content of his column happened to be XHTML (well defined/well formed HTML would not be sufficient).  Clearly you understand the issue at hand, but that wasn't obvious from your original post or your comments.  Once again, I'm sorry to have ruffled your feathers.

Comment: The example works gr8. But not for my data. My example data : `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>*******</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><P><A HREF="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</A></P><div><A HREF="http://www.yahoo.com">YAHOO</A></DIV><TABLE><TR><TD><A HREF="http://www.bing.com">BING</A></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML> ` So A HREF will be available inside of any tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per the @Barmar suggestion, i searched in google and got 1 solution.

user defined functions for PREG.(Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)
http://www.mysqludf.org/
https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme
All functions seems good and we can apply regular expression as like any other language (Perl, PHP etc)

NOTE: But it requires, c++ program compilation and installation to mysql